# Creating a compression tunnel

Tags: linux, compression, tunnel

I'm trying to compress all traffic on port 6999 and pipe it out onto port 7000. I was thinking of creating a tunnel for this. I would like to use Intel's performance primitive compression library rather than gzip et al.

Any thoughts or ideas greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Never heard of intel's performance primitives, but I think (hope) that gzip & others tools are "automatically" optimized for processor-level features. In particular, I expect that gcc outputs optimized code for each platform, so to use advanced instruction set (e.g., MMX instructions).

Comment: I'm sure gzip does a good job. Intel's performance primitives are optimized for Intel hardware, so should do an even better job.

Comment: I repeat myself: you can activate IPP optimizations while you compile gzip (or similar). See, for instance, http://encode.ru/threads/476-gzip-Intel-IPP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo 'hello world' > a
$ nc -l 6999 | gzip | nc -l 7000 &
[1] 3004
$ nc localhost 6999 < a
$ nc localhost 7000 > b
[1]+  Done                    nc -l 6999 | gzip | nc -l 7000
$ gzip -d < b > c
$ md5sum a b c
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  a
74e8a26018c51612ce9257cff9f75c95  b
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  c
```

Comment: Any user space based solution will not be 100% transparent. For example, source address will be different.

Comment: Mmm. Very interesting command line gymnastics there! But I don't quite follow what to do next?! Also, does this always write to disk? I'd prefer to do it all in memory rather than write to disk. Many thanks though!

Comment: I mean, how could I wrap all of this up into a script? Also, is it possible to just compress outgoing traffic and decompress incoming traffic?

Comment: @Eamorr: It's all in memory. The files I use are at the end points, they have nothing to do with the pipeline. You could connect to the ports in your own code using TCP if you wanted. It can be wrapped in a script. You could do all your compression/decompression by invoking a combination of 2 gzip instances and a single nc with their stdin/stdout handles connected correctly. Note that the demo above is limited in that if the pipeline buffers fill, it will stall. The input and extraction of a and b need to be simultaneous to avoid this, which is another problem altogether.

Comment: Hi Matt, very interesting stuff. To be honest, I don't really know how to start. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this: I have two machines remote and core. I want to compress all traffic (port 7000) between the two machines as follows: 1. HTTP requests from remote are compressed; 2. sent to core (where they're decompressed); 3. the response from core is compressed and sent on to remote before, 4. being decompressed on remote. Could you please make some further suggestions as to how to go about this? Also, you mentioned that I'd need to extract a and b together? Not sure... Many thanks!

Comment: @Eamorr: Ask another question. Always ask how to achieve what you want, not what you think you need. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Cheers Matt! You learn something new every day. I've currently lost interest in your method and am looking at using an ssh tunnel (with encryption turned off and compression turned on) instead. I have indeed asked another question: http://serverfault.com/questions/286137/forward-all-traffic-through-an-ssh-tunnel/286143#comment-268523

Comment: `gzip -d < b > c`  => does this mean decompress b (stdin) and tunnel the result to c (stdout) ?